# How we integrate library on magento-2 custom extension

Tags: magento2

I want to add my custom library file in my custom extension.

How we integrate library on magento-2 custom extension?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way would be to install it via composer.

depends on the library. It has to have a composer.json with autoloading settings defined.

if the library has a valid composer.json you can install it with the following command in your magento2 root:

composer require vendor/name:version

with vendor/name = the name that is defined in the composer.json

OR

You should do two steps to work with that library:

Download it with your module
Make it available to the autoloader
The best way to solve all these steps is to find your library in Packagist and add it as a dependency in your module's composer.json.

If it is not available as composer package, you have another two options:

Declare its package as a [repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories) and add dependency in 'required' section
Bundle it inside your package
Also if it's not a composer package, you'll need to configure your autoloader to work with that library. [Here is a documentation for that.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

```
{
...
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php",
        "path-to-generated-soap-client-lib-autoload.php"
    ],
    ...
}
```

}

Comment: Without composer  i want to add my custom file library add in my custom extention.

Comment: I have edited my comments, I think this will help you.Let me know if you want another method.